# How to tar each directory as seperate file and keep the tar in another directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

I found examples of tar all directories, but it keeps it in the same directory.

I want to keep the tar in a separate directory from the regular file structure.

So far I have something like this, but the `basename` truncates the name of the directories I have. For example, some directories are www.example.com and it ends up showing me www.tar.gz.

```
WEBROOT="var/www"
BAKPATH="/var/backups/"

for vhost in $WEBROOT; do
  base=$(basename "$vhost")
  tar -czf $BAKPATH/"`date +%Y-%m-%d`_${base}.tar.gz" "$vhost"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `/*` after `$WEBROOT`, and there may be a `cd` missing:

```bash
for vhost in "$WEBROOT"/*/; do
  base=$(basename "$vhost")
  ( cd "$WEBROOT" && tar -czf "$BAKPATH/$(date +%F)_$base.tar.gz" "$base" )
done
```

The `/` after `"$WEBROOT/*` guarantees that we only match directories.

This will create archives in `$BAKPATH` that will have the `$base` as their top-level directory.

---

The following is almost exactly equivalent:

```
find "$WEBROOT" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
    -execdir tar -czf "$BAKPATH/$(date +%F)"_{}.tar.gz {} \;
```

Comment: And if you append another `/` after the `*` then you can skip the `test -d`.

Comment: @Wildcard It took a bit of time, but I've fixed that now. Thanks.